# Почему phpstorm не дает подключить библиотеки bootstrap в режиме Debug (Live Edit)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, phpstorm

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <span class="badge badge-primary">Hello world</span>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Если просто запустить код, то всё будет ОК. Но если я запущу файл в режиме отладки (для того чтобы использовать Live edit), css код не сработает, и phpstorm по какой-то причине будет блочить подключение скриптов и css файлов. 
**Вопрос: Как сделать так, чтобы можно было подключать сторонние скрипты и css в режиме отладки?** 

**P.S. список ошибок:**

Access to script at 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js' from origin 'http://localhost:63342' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

GET https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js net::ERR_FAILED

Access to CSS stylesheet at 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css' from origin 'http://localhost:63342' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

GET https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css net::ERR_FAILED

Access to script at 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js' from origin 'http://localhost:63342' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field x-ijt is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

GET https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js net::ERR_FAILED

Access to script at 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js' from origin 'http://localhost:63342' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

GET https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js net::ERR_FAILED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте включить опцию **Allow unsigned requests** в **Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger** и перестартуйте IDE

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста подсказать, как подключать изображения на страницу в режиме Debug (Live Edit)? Выдается ошибка: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: если вы используете встроенный веб сервер ( 'http://localhost:63342' ) для хостинга вашей странички, не используйте абсолютные пути (начинающиеся со слэша) в URLs, используйте только относительные пути (относительно .html файла)